# What does "Hairy at the heel" mean?

Tags: meaning

I see this a lot in a lot of books I read. Does anyone have an answer for this? It sounds like an idiom, but I cannot find any answers on the Internet.

Comment: According to [Bank Soal & Strategi TOEFL](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=D0SMBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA309&dq=%22Hairy+at+the+heel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f3VwVaHoIOTD7gaS9IHwBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Hairy%20at%20the%20heel%22&f=false), *Someone who is **hairy at the heel** is dangerous or untrustworthy*. They say *(**UK**)* - I never heard it before, but apparently [Agatha Christie used it several times in her books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hairy+at+the+heel%22+%22Agatha+Christie%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). As to "etymology", I've no idea, obviously.

Comment: Long before Agatha Christie, [*Horace Annesley Vachell*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hairy+at+the+heel%22+vachell&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (also English) used it in at least two different books. Harrow schoolboy slang, perhaps?

Comment: This page says it comes from horse-breeding milieu: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-hai2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One example appears in a story about Ms Christie’s Belgian detective Hercule Poirot:
>
> “The Colonel delivered himself of the opinion that Godfrey Burrows was slightly hairy at the heel, a pronouncement which baffled Poirot completely.”
>
> His understandable bewilderment is a state he shares, I suspect, with most readers. Walter James Macqueen-Pope made its meaning clearer in Back Numbers in 1954, in which he described someone as “**a cad, a bounder, an outsider, hairy at the heel.**” Putting it simply, **such a person was ill-bred**.
>   […]
>
> It used to be said that it was a sign of poor breeding if a horse had too much hair about the fetlocks.

Source: [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-hai2.htm)

Comment: Looks like from the comments that this is an idiom.

Comment: The earliest related usage I can find is 1833 [*we never saw a lady's fine-limbed palfrey at the plough, nor a **hairy-heeled cart-horse** used as a roadster.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+hairy-heeled+cart-horse%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Clearly the "poor breeding" you refer to implies to the horse having characteristics typical of a plodding *dray-horse*, rather than a *racing horse* (or whatever type of horse the gentry of the time would feel appropriate for their general personal transport)..